# Processing a Message Queue and Using Async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, azure, azure-storage

I wrote a small test node app that loops and adds messages to a queue (azure storage queue), something like this:

```js
var queueService = azure.createQueueService();
var queueName = 'taskqueue';

// other stuff like check if created

// loop called after queue is confirmed

for (i=0;i<1000;i++){
  queueService.createMessage(queueName, "Hello world!", null, messageCreated);
}

// messageCreated does nothing at the moment, just logs to console
```

I'm trying to rewrite that to handle say 1 million create's using async to control the number of worker functions that are run in parallel.  This is a learning exercise more than anything.

https://github.com/caolan/async#queue

This is the basic setup for async's queue and I'm kind of at a loss as to what I need to change. I don't think the below will work:

```js
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
   queueService.createMessage(queueName, task.msg, null, messageCreated);
    callback();
}, 100);


// assign a callback.  Called when all the queues have been processed
q.drain = function() {
    console.log('all items have been processed');
}

// add some items to the queue
for(i=0;i<1000000;i++) {
  q.push({msg: 'Hello World'}, function (err) {
    console.log('finished processing foo');
  });
    console.log('pushing: ' + i);
}
```

I'm not quite grasping how to pull it all together with async.

Comment: quiickly skimming this looks okay to me..?

Comment: @Alfred, I changed the million to 500 for testing. What ends up happening is I see "finished processing foo" printed to the screen 500 times and then the first console log from messageCreated (the callback from the azure put message)..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's your error:

```js
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
   queueService.createMessage(queueName, task.msg, null, messageCreated);
    callback();
}, 100);
```

What you are doing is creating a message on the queue, and immediately afterwards pass the continuation (calling the callback). What you want to do is to pass continuation inside the callback passed to `createMessage`:

```js
var q = async.queue(function (task, callback) {
   queueService.createMessage(queueName, task.msg, null, function(error, serverQueue, serverResponse) {
       callback(error, serverQueue, serverResponse);
       messageCreated(error, serverQueue, serverResponse);
   });
}, 100);
```

Now each task will report finishing after the task has actually been created.

**Edit:** Updated interface for the `createMessage` callback.

Comment: The *callback* for `createMessage` is `function messageCreated(error, serverQueue, serverResponse)`  so I can't call it like you have it.. This is where my confusion exists.

Comment: In the for loop where the push is occuring, if I console.log after the push: `console.log('pushing: ' + i);` would you expect to see `i` printed out 1000000 times and then the queue start processing or would you expect the queue to start processing  at the same time as as the for loop is processing?  For instance, I'd expec to see `pushing: 1 pushing: 2 pushing: 3 finished processing foo pushing: 4` etc

Comment: By processing I meant that the callbacks for the createMessage would be firing prior to the for loop completing.

Comment: That's hard to say, depending on how fast `createMessage` is vs `push`. You tell me!

Comment: I can tell you that it takes a minute or two to run through a million and not one time did I receive a callback for the createMessage until after the for loop was done processing.  The push usually takes a second or two to return.